# Fontspec warning about lining numbers not being available in font

Tags: fontspec

Using the sans serif font Linux Biolinum, I set the `Numbers` option to `Lining`, in order to use normal numbers. This gives the following warning message (twice):

```
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "icu-feature-not-exist-in-font"
* 
* OpenType feature 'Numbers=Lining' (+lnum) not available for font 'Linux
* Biolinum O/B' with script 'Latin' and language 'Default'.
*************************************************
```

The output nevertheless correctly prints normal lining numbers. What's going on here? Below a MWE with output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont[Numbers = Lining]{Linux Biolinum O}

\begin{document}
Numbers: \textsf{0123456789}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe `fontspec` changing font for numbers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

this works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[RawFeature=+onum]{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont[RawFeature=+lnum]{Linux Biolinum O}

\begin{document}
0123456789
Numbers: \textsf{0123456789}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: According to the documentation of `fontspec` the option `Numbers=Lining` should set the font feature `lnum`, shouldn't it? And since this feature exists in Linux Biolinum O the warning is at least misleading.

Comment: I want to set it because I normally use ``Numbers = OldStyle``, so I want to see when I use lining numbers instead.

That said - I have a suspicion that ``RawFeature=+lnum`` is ignored. I first copied your initial reply with the typo ``RawFeature=+lum``, and it compiled without warnings, and printed lining numbers.

Comment: @cgnieder: I agree. The font clearly has lining numbers, so I'm puzzled why ``fontspec`` gives me this warning. It gives me no warning if I set ``Numbers = OldStyle``.

Comment: @Sverre:ok, understood. I edited my example which works for oldstyle and lining numbers

Comment: @cgnieder: it maybe a problem with the script and language setting inside Biolinum

Comment: @Herbert I wonder if one should report this to the font developers? (I'm tempted to do so.)

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem with another font. I think it's a problem with the way the font is set up, rather than a problem with Fontspec.

I think what's happening is: Fontspec tries to enable a feature that hasn't been correctly tagged in the font, so it fails and goes back to the default configuration, printing uppercase numbers as desired.

To test this hypothesis, I tried a version of the above answer, essentially reversing the enabling of old style figures: `\addfontfeature{RawFeature=-onum}`

This works perfectly fine and avoids warnings.

Answer (score 0):

The bold variant of Linux Biolinum doesn't have the lnum feature (but does have lining numbers). This may explain why the warning is produced.

Comment: So does the 'B' in 'Linux Biolinum O/B' in the warning message stand for 'bold' then? I'm still somewhat puzzled what it means to not have the lnum feature, but nevertheless have lining numbers, but this might be a font specific thing I have no knowledge of.